# Restricting access to built-in secondary display in Android

Tags: android, android-multi-display

I have a device with a built-in secondary display (*i.e.*, a physical display). I can root that device and access its configuration and file system.

I'm looking for a way to restrict access to the secondary display, something along the lines of "only apps with permission X can launch activities on the secondary display". Is there a way to do that?

I've already looked into Android's Multi-Display "[Recommended practices](https://source.android.com/docs/core/display/multi_display/recommended-practices#restriction)" page but it seems to me the information there is only relevant for virtual displays that are created on the fly?